# How to call print() with colorful text to android studio console in flutter

Tags: colors, dart, flutter

I need a debug output with colorful string, like node.js chalk.

I tried to find the packages, but there is no proper package.

Comment: here you have some tips: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: try this one https://pub.dev/packages/logger#logger-flutter-extension

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to print escape sequences to get the color effects in terminal output.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ansicolor is a Dart package that makes this easy.

Comment: It doesn't work on my android studio. Escape chars are ignored. import 'dart:io' as io;print(io.stdout.supportsAnsiEscapes);  return false.

Answer (score 76):

I created the screenshots and code below in [VS Code](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1425), but supposedly it also works in Android Studio now too:

[image]

```dart
void main() {
  print('This is a normal message.');
  printWarning('This is a warning.');
  printError('This is an error.');
}

void printWarning(String text) {
  print('\x1B[33m$text\x1B[0m');
}

void printError(String text) {
  print('\x1B[31m$text\x1B[0m');
}
```

### ANSI escape code explanation

The ANSI escape code string is pretty confusing if you're not familiar with the format.

[image]

Here is the string to turn `Hello` red:

```
\x1B[31mHello\x1B[0m
```

And here it is again with spaces added for clarity between the parts:

```
\x1B  [31m  Hello  \x1B  [0m
```

Meaning:

- `\x1B`: ANSI escape sequence starting marker
- `[31m`: Escape sequence for red
- `[0m`: Escape sequence for reset (stop making the text red)

Here are the other colors:

```
Black:   \x1B[30m
Red:     \x1B[31m
Green:   \x1B[32m
Yellow:  \x1B[33m
Blue:    \x1B[34m
Magenta: \x1B[35m
Cyan:    \x1B[36m
White:   \x1B[37m
Reset:   \x1B[0m
```

Learn more from these links:

- [Build your own Command Line with ANSI escape codes](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html)
- [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: In my case, i need to put inside developer.log('...') to see the colors.

Comment: Works for me in Android Studio 3.6.3. (Using print(), not developer.log()) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 21):

## Emoji

You can use colors for text as others mentioned in their answers to have colorful text with a background or foreground color.

But you can use **emojis** instead! for example, you can use`⚠️` for warning messages and  for error messages.

Or simply use these notebooks as a color:

```
: error message
: warning message
: ok status message
: action message
: canceled status message
: Or anything you like and want to recognize immediately by color
```

#### Bonus:

This method also helps you to quickly scan and find logs **directly in the source code**.

<sub>But some distributions of Linux’s default emoji font is not colorful by default and you may want to make them colorful, first.</sub>

---

#### How to open emoji panel?

[**mac os**:](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/mac) <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

[**windows**:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-keyboard-tips-and-tricks-588e0b72-0fff-6d3f-aeee-6e5116097942) <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

[**linux**:](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/use-emoji-linux-ubuntu-apps) <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> or  <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) if you don't want to change the way you actually print the characters

You can add a tag like `[DEBUG]` to your logs and grep console would do the magic for you.

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to share my **Logger** using the Enhanced Enums.
It works with [Flutter 3](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.0.0) and minimum Dart SDK version is `2.17.0`.

```dart
enum Logger {
  Black("30"),
  Red("31"),
  Green("32"),
  Yellow("33"),
  Blue("34"),
  Magenta("35"),
  Cyan("36"),
  White("37");

  final String code;
  const Logger(this.code);

  void log(dynamic text) =>
      print('\x1B[' + code+ 'm' + text.toString() + '\x1B[0m');
}
```

Example:

```dart
Logger.Green.log("I Love Coffee!");
```

Answer (score 6):

Though text coloring works perfect in terminal it may not work in debug output of IDE (I've tried Idea/Android Studio and VSCode).

Example of ANSI Escape Codes using:

`print('\x1B[94m' + "hahAHaHA!!!" + '\x1B[0m');`

Examples of using `ansicolor` package:

```
import 'package:ansicolor/ansicolor.dart';

main(List<String> arguments) {
  AnsiPen greenPen = AnsiPen()..green();
  AnsiPen greenBackGroundPen = AnsiPen()..green(bg: true);

  AnsiPen redTextBlueBackgroundPen = AnsiPen()..blue(bg: true)..red();

  AnsiPen boldPen = AnsiPen()..white(bold: true);

  AnsiPen someColorPen = AnsiPen()..rgb(r: .5, g: .2, b: .4);

  print(greenPen("Hulk") + " " + greenBackGroundPen("SMASH!!!"));
  print(redTextBlueBackgroundPen("Spider-Man!!!") + " " + boldPen("Far From Home!!!"));

  print(someColorPen("Chameleon"));
}
```

---

PS Came here to find some info on text coloring in terminal, not in debug output of IDE. So I decided to write examples here and do not create separate question with answer.

Comment: ANSI escape codes work great for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Styles & Colors in any IDE

[image]

[image]

There is a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_console) that is just as natural as `print()`. Simply call `printRich()`instead.

```dart
printRich("This is my String", foreground: Colors.blue, italic: true);

printWarning("This is a very important warning"); //Will be yellow
```

You can change fore- and background colors and adjust text styles (italic, bold, underline, etc.). This package should work with any IDE as long as it uses ANSI (most IDEs can display this, including Android Studio).

Comment: This is truly working in Android Studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Dart console does not parse ANSI colors in Android Studio or IntelliJ Idea.
You can check ANSI color support by calling

```
import dart.io as io
io.stdout.supportsAnsiEscapes
```

But you can have colorful logs in Android Studio, just open a terminal window in android studio and call

```
flutter logs
```

This command attaches the current terminal session to the active flutter session.
Use this terminal for logs. Debug tab, for other functionality.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2NdN.png)

Comment: The terminal in Android Studio supports ANSI colors, so does the Windows Power Shell, `flutter logs` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;


void printW(String text) {
  developer.log('\x1B[33m$text\x1B[0m');
}

void printE(String text) {
  developer.log('\x1B[31m$text\x1B[0m');
}

void printI(String text) {
  developer.log('\x1B[36m$text\x1B[0m');
}

void printS(String text) {
  developer.log('\x1B[32m$text\x1B[0m');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**USE CASE**

```
            prettyPrint(tag: "Profile", value: "200", type: DebugType.statusCode);
            prettyPrint(tag: "Profile", value: "Wrong password entered", type: DebugType.error);
            prettyPrint(tag: "Profile", value: "google.com", type: DebugType.url);
            prettyPrint(tag: "Profile", value: "key_id", type: DebugType.info);
            prettyPrint(tag: "Profile", value: "API response", type: DebugType.response);
```

**UTILITY**

```
                import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
                
                enum DebugType { error, info, url, response, statusCode }
                
                prettyPrint(
                    {required String tag,
                    required dynamic value,
                    DebugType type = DebugType.info}) {
                  switch (type) {
                    case DebugType.statusCode:
                      {
                        debugPrint('\x1B[33m${" STATUS CODE $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
                        break;
                      }
                    case DebugType.info:
                      {
                        debugPrint('\x1B[32m${"⚡ INFO $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
                        break;
                      }
                    case DebugType.error:
                      {
                        debugPrint('\x1B[31m${" ERROR $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
                        break;
                      }
                    case DebugType.response:
                      {
                        debugPrint('\x1B[36m${" RESPONSE $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
                        break;
                      }
                    case DebugType.url:
                      {
                        debugPrint('\x1B[34m${" URL $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
                        break;
                      }
                  }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved from above code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void printDebug(Object? object) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(object);
  }
}

Map<String, Stopwatch> _statusMaps = Map<String, Stopwatch>();
void startTimer(String name) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    var _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
    _stopwatch.start();
    var status = '${name} starting\n';
    _statusMaps[name] = _stopwatch;
    printCustom("Timer", status);
  }
}

void stopTimer(String name) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    Stopwatch _stopwatch;
    if (_statusMaps.containsKey(name)) {
      _stopwatch = _statusMaps[name]!;
      var status = '${name} executed in ${_stopwatch.elapsed}';
      printCustom("Timer", status);
      _statusMaps.remove(name);
    }
  }
}

printCustom(String name, String status, [String charater = '⚡']) {
  debugPrint('\x1B[33m${"$charater $name: $status"}\x1B[0m');
}

enum DebugType { error, info, url, response, statusCode }

prettyPrint(
    {required String tag,
    required dynamic value,
    DebugType type = DebugType.info}) {
  switch (type) {
    case DebugType.statusCode:
      {
        debugPrint('\x1B[33m${" STATUS CODE $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
        break;
      }
    case DebugType.info:
      {
        debugPrint('\x1B[32m${"⚡ INFO $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
        break;
      }
    case DebugType.error:
      {
        debugPrint('\x1B[31m${" ERROR $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
        break;
      }
    case DebugType.response:
      {
        debugPrint('\x1B[36m${" RESPONSE $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
        break;
      }
    case DebugType.url:
      {
        debugPrint('\x1B[34m${" URL $tag: $value"}\x1B[0m');
        break;
      }
  }
}
```